# Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes() / Encoding.Default.GetString() / Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have programmed a server and a client application under Xamarin C# (for PC and Android phone).

Now I have a problem with the umlauts (äöüÄÖÜ) at Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes () / Encoding.Default.GetString ().

If the server and client running on the PC, umlauts are converted correctly. When operated smartphone and PC only question marks will be issued on conversion of umlauts. All other data is converted properly.

Where is the problem?

```
    private void cButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cAktiveClient == "") Toast.MakeText(this, "Wählen Sie einen Client aus!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            else
            {
                string txt = cSendeText.Text;
                byte[] telegramm = new byte[txt.Length];
                telegramm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txt);

                foreach (TcpClient c in cServer.ClientList)
                {
                    if (c.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() == cAktiveClient) cServer.Send(c, telegramm);
                }
                cSendeText.Text = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }


    private void cServer_Recieve(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // bei Aufrufen aus anderenThreads
        this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                TCPIP_MultiServer t = sender as TCPIP_MultiServer;
                cEmpfangsClient.Text = t.NowClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                cEmpfangsText.Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(cServer.Buffer, 0, cServer.RecievedBytes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please ask your question in English, as questions and answers are supposed to be readable by people worldwide.

Comment: I would say you should use English)) More chances to get the solution to your problem

Comment: Even though I am german myself, I highly encourage you to respect the rules of StackOverflow and ask / answer questions in english!

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the size of the application, Xamarin doesn't include any specific encodings.

Read this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/encodings/ (on Android it's the same)

And this:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/